# How to extract and assign data from cURL output?

Tags: php, xml, curl

The code:

```
function GetCurlPage ($pageSpec)
{
$ch = curl_init($pageSpec);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, FALSE);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE);
$tmp = curl_exec ($ch);
curl_close ($ch);
$tmp = preg_replace('/(?s)<meta http-equiv="Expires"[^>]*>/i', '', $tmp);
return $tmp;
}

$url = "https://www.domain.com/check.php?domain=" .
$domain . "&suffixes=" . $suffixes . "&fuzzysearch=" . $fuzzysearch;
$output = GetCurlPage("$url");

print $output;
```

It outputs 3 lines of html, however I wanted to assign a variable to each line to then do something with it...

Ie:

```
if ($line_1_of_output=="Hi")
{
"do something"
}

if ($line_2_of_output=="Hi")
{
"do something else"
}
```

How can I output each line in it's own variable in XML if this is the best way to go about it?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unless I am misunderstanding you, you can just explode cURL's output and then loop through the array.

```
<?php
// cURL code...
$tmp = explode("<br>", $tmp);

foreach ($tmp AS $lnum => $line) {
  var_dump($line);
  echo '<br>';
}
```

Try this:

```
function GetCurlPage ($pageSpec)
{
  $ch = curl_init($pageSpec);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, FALSE);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE);
  $tmp = curl_exec ($ch);
  curl_close ($ch);
  $tmp = preg_replace('/(?s)<meta http-equiv="Expires"[^>]*>/i', '', $tmp);
  $tmp = explode('<br>', $tmp);

  // Test the array.
  foreach ($tmp AS $line) {
    echo '<pre>';
    print_r($line);
    echo '</pre>';
  }

  // Do something with each line.
  $tmp[0] = str_replace('foo', 'bar', $tmp[0]);
  $tmp[1] = str_replace('animal', 'monkey', $tmp[1]);
  $tmp[2] = str_replace('cat', 'dog', $tmp[2]);

  return $tmp;
}
```

Comment: So will that ouput each line into 3 separate variables which I can then do checks with if statements on?

Comment: Once you explode by \n, each line is a separate element in $tmp (e.g. $tmp[0], $tmp[1], $tmp[2])

Comment: Ok I've tried testing output of the tmp array..

foreach ($tmp AS $lnum => $line) {
  echo $tmp[0];
}

No output :/

Comment: Hmmm it's just not outputting the specific line when calling $tmp[0] or any position in the array

Comment: Maybe the output of cURL has a different line format.  Try \r instead, and if that doesn't work, \r\n

Comment: Still nothing :( when i print output$; it output the following: available: <br>not available: desk<br>failure:

Comment: Are you sure there are actual carriage returns or new lines in the output, and its not just <br>'s causing new lines?  Do a `echo '<pre>'; print_r($curlOutput); echo '</pre>';` for the curl output, before exploding, and see if it shows the output on multiple lines.

Comment: source code: <pre></pre><pre></pre>Array<pre></pre>Array<pre></pre>Array<pre></pre>Array<pre></pre>Array<pre></pre>Array<pre></pre>Array<pre></pre>Array<pre></pre>Array<pre></pre>Array

Comment: And I'm 100% sure it's not carriage returns causing new lines. Definitely the <br>'s doing it. So it looks like I confused you to begin with, sorry.
So to my original Question, how can I grab each bit of output (available, not available, failure) and set vairables for each to then do checks with other stuff?

Comment: Explode on `<br>` instead then.  (You may want to trim each element of the array afterwards too.)

Comment: Not a prob, thanks. Just ran a test. $tmp = explode("<br>", $tmp);
foreach ($tmp AS $lnum => $line) {
  echo $tmp[0];
  echo $tmp[1];
  echo $tmp[2];
}
 Output was: ArrayArrayArrayArrayArrayArrayArrayArrayArrayArray (running a 10 count loop)

Comment: I edited my response, try it and then tell me what you get.  Each $line should not be an array.  If it is, then you are doing something extra that's causing it to be.

Comment: Ouput is: string(0) ""
string(5) "Array"
string(5) "Array"
string(5) "Array"
string(5) "Array"
string(5) "Array"
string(5) "Array"
string(5) "Array"
string(5) "Array"
string(5) "Array"
string(5) "Array"

Comment: Are you positive that $tmp is not being affected anywhere else?  Like I said in the last comment, each $line in $tmp should **not** be an array.

Comment: I noticed that. I added some missing code into my original post. Particularly watch out for $output = GetCurlPage("$url");. $tmp is not affected anywhere else.

Comment: Just to be sure you're doing it right, use what I posted in my response above.

Comment: GENIOUS! Thank you so much simshaun!!! So now distinguishing between each line? ie: line1, line2 and line 3 variables?